# Database for storing large document with partial text retrival based on location

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, document

I am looking for a database system where I can store a large document (10-20MB) and do the following:

- Be able to access content in a given document by location. Example, fetch text between location 100 to 500.
- Database should return only partial content from the document (without loading the whole document may be). So I am looking for efficiency.
- Should handle insert, update and delete text blocks in specified location (or range).
- I want to use these locations to define boundaries. For example, location 100 to 500 is page no. 4

This will be used with a web application where users will create contents in form of continuous documents (example, one document is a simplified Google doc with 100s of pages). I have thought about MongoDB, but I don't know enough about it.

-

What kind of database could I use here? (I am looking for an open-source database)

OR

If I have to write such system on my own what should be my approach and where could I start?

Thank you :)

Comment: MongoDB has a limit of 16MB per document (a database entry in MongoDB lingua). It also doesn't offer tools for string manipulation inside of documents. You could find workarounds for both problems (splitting each document into sections / doing the string manipulation on the application layer), but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I read about that limit and I think that limit is probably OK for me as long as I can do index based lookups within that document. I could do what you suggest, about breaking the document into sections. The problem is that when the new text is inserted in the middle I would require to update all the subsequent sections since text blocks will move. It's like in a word doc. if I insert a paragraph, all the subsequent pages need to be updated as text blocks move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive always felt uncomfortable putting files inside a database; the filesystem is the ideal database for files (you are not limited in size to what your o/s can handle), the indexing/search can be handled by a separate application and your database can be reduced to a simple table containing uri-esque links back to each actual file in your system and any other appropriate meta data.

In your case, a file indexer/search engine like [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) may be a better fit for your project than trying to use a traditional DMBS as a filesystem.

Since you are planning on putting your content into a database I am assuming you will have control over how documents are added to your system. This allows you to more easily and highly integrate your presentation layer with your filesystem data store without worrying about files being dropped, changed or removed willy nilly into your special repository.

So a very very basic high level system overview might look something like this:

```
[(APP) Your System]---------[(DB) Catalog ]
           |       \              |
           |        --------      |
           |                \     |
[(FileSystem) Files]--------[(App) Indexer]
```

With Your system doing all the smarts of the document maintenance and front facing searching and the Indexer monitoring the File System and updating the Catalog DB. (The Catalog may be unnecessary if your indexer ends up providing sufficient functionality or the ability to add meta data - but it might be easier to use in conjunction with the indexer if you really need to searches based on 'documents between 100 and 300')

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer, I see your point about putting files in database. If the content of the file can be structured then it could be a good idea to use a database. I have not progressed with my project idea, but if I do in the future I will keep your idea in mind.